# Meaning of more likely or less likely in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose, I'm performing a certain experiment with many outcomes corresponding to $4$ events - $A,B,C,D$.

We have been given the following data : $$p(A)>p(B),p(C),p(D)$$

$$p(A)<p(A^c)$$

This means, in a single trial $A$ is **more likely** to occur than other events  $B,C,D$, since it has a higher probability.

However, if we carry out the same experiment many-many times, we'd get a lot of different results, and from these results we'd expect $A$ to be the **mode**, but there will be **more results** where $A$ **does not happen**, **than those** where $A$ **does happen**. This is because, even though the **individual probabilities** of $B,C,D$ are less than that of $A$, the combined probability is larger. Thus, in the final tally, $A$ would happen more than $B,C,D$ individually, but there will be more outcomes where $A$ does not happen.

From this perspective, $A$ is **less likely** to occur.

So, in a single trial $A$ is more likely to occur than others, but from the perspective of multiple trials, $A$ is less likely to occur.

An example is an event of $100$ coin tosses. The probability of getting $50$ heads is roughly $8$ percent. This is more than any other probability. Does this then imply, that in a single trial we are most likely to obtain an equal number of heads and tails, but if we repeat the experiment many times, there will simply be many more cases of not getting equal amounts of heads and tails? So, from the perspective of many trials, getting an equal amount of heads and tails is less likely, even though in a single trial it is most likely ?

In a single trial, we compare the probabilities of individual events to determine what is most likely. However, in many trials, we compare the probability of something happening against that same thing not happening, to determine if it is likely to happen or not.

Is this a correct interpretation of what is meant by more or less likely in probability? Can someone verify this for me?

The answers to this [question]:(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262339/feynman-random-walk) seems to talk about this thing - but I'm not being able to interpret this correctly)

Can anyone tell me, if the above interpretation is correct ?

Comment: $A$ is more likely than any one of $B$, $C$, $D$, but it is less likely than $B \cup C \cup D$. What's the problem with that?

Comment: You keep asking the same question.  It's not a math question, it's a grammar question.  If I say that Bob is the tallest person in the room, that means he is taller than every other person in the room, and that's all it means.  If you look at people in some other room, Bob might not be the tallest.  If you add up the heights of every one else in the room, their combined height might be taller than Bob's.  That's all that's going on here.

Comment: To stress:  When we say that $A_1$ is the most likely of the events $\{A_n\}$ all we mean is that $P(A_1)≥P(A_i)$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots, n\}$.  We don't mean anything else.  Maybe $P(A_1)<P(A_2\cup A_3)$, why not?  That simply isn't covered by the original statement.

Comment: It means that if you had to guess a specific number of heads that will come up, you should probably guess $50$, but that doesn't mean that it's incredibly likely that exactly $50$ heads will show up.  It's just your best guess (most likely to be correct) out of the choices you have.

Comment: You could think of it as saying "If I had to make a guess, $50$ is the best one, but I think any guess I make is pretty likely to be wrong."

Comment: @user6247850 ah, so basically, if I do the experiment many times, since 50 is my best guess, I'll expect it to show up more than others ( since it has highest probability ).  However, this doesn't mean I'd mostly get 50 heads in all my trials. In fact I'd get a wide range of values. That is correct, right ?

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay Yes, that is exactly correct.

Comment: @user6247850 also since getting that has highest probability compared to the other events, over a large number of trials we'll expect it to show up more than the others individually as the mode of the distribution. However, since it is lesser than its compliment, we'd also expect it to show up less than the others combined. Am I correct ?

Comment: A compliment is a nice thing you say to someone. It's different from a complement.